# Tradingview pinscript. Return last time a condition is met

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

So I'm using the fractal indicator for my script but I need to return last fractal value in alerts. For this I need each candle to return the value of the last fractal signal (please not that I have not put the highest() and lowest() function now but I will)

So this is what my code looks like :

```html
fTop = high[4] < high[2] and high[3] < high[2] and high[2] > high[1] and high[2] > high[0]
fBottom= low[4] > low[2] and low[3] > low[2] and low[2] < low[1] and low[2] < low[0]

plotshape(fTop ? close : na, title='Top Fractals', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, offset=-2)
plotshape(fBottom ? close : na, title='Bottom Fractals', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.belowbar, color=color.blue, offset=-2)
```

For now the script return "na" if I'm not on a condition met candle. I tried to put fTop[1] / fBottom[1], but it return last candle and not last condition... Anyone having a solution ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

*I need to return last fractal value*

The solution below will plot the fractal's close price. Note that your fractal have a negative offset 2, so the close series has a 2 bar history reference.

```
//@version=4
study("Fractal", overlay = true)

fTop = high[4] < high[2] and high[3] < high[2] and high[2] > high[1] and high[2] > high[0]
fBottom= low[4] > low[2] and low[3] > low[2] and low[2] < low[1] and low[2] < low[0]

plotshape(fTop ? close : na, title='Top Fractals', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, offset=-2)
plotshape(fBottom ? close : na, title='Bottom Fractals', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.belowbar, color=color.blue, offset=-2)

var float fixTop = na
var float fixBot = na

if fTop
    fixTop := close[2]
else if fBottom
    fixBot := close[2]


plot(fixTop, change(fixTop) ? na : color.green, style = plot.style_linebr, offset = -2)
plot(fixBot, change(fixBot) ? na : color.red, style = plot.style_linebr, offset = -2)
```

[image]

To return the High/Low value of the fractal change this part of the code:

```
if fTop
    fixTop := high[2]
else if fBottom
    fixBot := low[2]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm trying but I have this error `Cannot call 'plot' with arguments (series[float], series[color], style=const integer); available overloads: plot(series[float], const string, series[color], input integer, input integer, input bool, input integer, input float, series[integer], input bool, series[float], const bool, input integer, const integer, string) => plot; plot(<arg_series_type>, const string, <arg_color_type>, input integer, input integer, input bool, input integer, input float, series[integer], input bool, series[float], const bool, input integer, const integer, string) => plot;`

Comment: The code snippet in my answer compiles without any problem. Make sure you copied the first line `//@version=4` as well.